# Python requests remove website from further checking if keyword found

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to remove the website from further checking process, if my "keyword" on the website got found, so they are not getting still checked multiple times.
How can i do this? Iam still a beginner but i linked you my whole Script at the bottom thanks.

If the keyword "google" got found at the currently checking website, i want to remove this website from further checking.

```
    if "google" in r2.text:
            print (bcolors.OKGREEN + "Parameters Found : " +server+ "/" + para1 + "/" + para2 + bcolors.ENDC)
            client = server + "," + para1 + "," + para2 + "\n"
            f = open('log.txt', 'a')
            f.write(client)
            f.close()
```

My whole Script

```
import os
import sys
from threading import Thread, BoundedSemaphore
from datetime import datetime
import optparse
import requests
import urllib3

os.system("color")
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()

maxConnections = 10
connection_lock = BoundedSemaphore(maxConnections)
time = datetime.now().time()

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'


def connect(server, para1, para2):
    try:
        r = requests.request('put', server + para1 + para2, timeout=30, verify=False, headers={'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'})
        r.close()      
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    r2 = requests.request('get', server + para1 + para2, verify=False, timeout=30, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'})
    r2.close()
    if "google" in r2.text:
            print (bcolors.OKGREEN + "Parameters Found : " +server+ "/" + para1 + "/" + para2 + bcolors.ENDC)
            client = server + "," + para1 + "," + para2 + "\n"
            f = open('log.txt', 'a')
            f.write(client)
            f.close()


def generate_tests(hosts, paras1, paras2):
    i = 0
    for para1 in paras1:
        para1 = para1.strip('\n\r')
        for para2 in paras2:
            para2 = para2.strip('\n\r')
            for host in hosts:
                server = host.strip('\n\r')
                print (bcolors.OKGREEN + "=" * 60 + bcolors.ENDC)
                print (bcolors.BOLD + "Website: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + server + para1 + para2 + bcolors.ENDC)
                print (bcolors.BOLD + "Parameter1: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + para1 + bcolors.ENDC)
                print (bcolors.BOLD + "Parameter2: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + para2 + bcolors.ENDC)
                i += 1
                print (bcolors.BOLD + "Attempts: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + str(i) + bcolors.ENDC)
                print (bcolors.BOLD + "Time Started: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + str(time) + bcolors.ENDC)
                print (bcolors.BOLD + "Time now: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + str(datetime.now().time()) + bcolors.ENDC)
                print (bcolors.OKGREEN + "=" * 60 + bcolors.ENDC)
                t = Thread(target=connect, args=(server, para1, para2))
                t.start()

def read_test_files(hostsfile, paras1file, paras2file):
    hosts = open(hostsfile, 'r').readlines()
    paras1 = open(paras1file, 'r').readlines()
    paras2 = open(paras2file, 'r').readlines()
    generate_tests(hosts, paras1, paras2)


def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage python test.py -H <hosts file> -U <para1 file> -P <para2 file>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='hostsfile', help="specify host file to test")
    parser.add_option('-U', dest='paras1file', help="specify possible parameters1")
    parser.add_option('-P', dest='paras2file', help="specify possible parameters2")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if options.hostsfile and options.paras1file and options.paras2file:
        hostsfile = options.hostsfile
        paras1file = options.paras1file
        paras2file = options.paras2file
        read_test_files(hostsfile, paras1file, paras2file)

    else:
        print (parser.usage)
        exit(0)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a collection of whitelists, which will be used to save websites that pass the check, and determine whether they are in the whitelist before starting the thread each time, and skip if they exist.

In the code below, the whitelist collection is temporary.

If you want it to take effect every time you start the program, you can save it to a file, read the file every time you start the program, and write it every time it ends.

```py
import os
import sys
from threading import Thread, BoundedSemaphore
from datetime import datetime
import optparse
import requests
import urllib3

os.system("color")
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()

maxConnections = 10
connection_lock = BoundedSemaphore(maxConnections)
time = datetime.now().time()

white_list = set()


class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'


def connect(server, para1, para2):
    try:
        r = requests.request('put', server + para1 + para2, timeout=30, verify=False,
                             headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
        r.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    r2 = requests.request('get', server + para1 + para2, verify=False, timeout=30, headers={
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'})
    r2.close()
    if "google" in r2.text:
        # add
        white_list.add(server)
        print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "Parameters Found : " + server + "/" + para1 + "/" + para2 + bcolors.ENDC)
        client = server + "," + para1 + "," + para2 + "\n"
        f = open('log.txt', 'a')
        f.write(client)
        f.close()


def generate_tests(hosts, paras1, paras2):
    i = 0
    for para1 in paras1:
        para1 = para1.strip('\n\r')
        for para2 in paras2:
            para2 = para2.strip('\n\r')
            for host in hosts:
                server = host.strip('\n\r')
                # Determine whether it is in the whitelist
                # The `host` in the whitelist has already been subjected to the `strip('\n\r')` operation.
                if server in white_list:
                    continue
                print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "=" * 60 + bcolors.ENDC)
                print(bcolors.BOLD + "Website: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + server + para1 + para2 + bcolors.ENDC)
                print(bcolors.BOLD + "Parameter1: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + para1 + bcolors.ENDC)
                print(bcolors.BOLD + "Parameter2: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + para2 + bcolors.ENDC)
                i += 1
                print(bcolors.BOLD + "Attempts: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + str(i) + bcolors.ENDC)
                print(bcolors.BOLD + "Time Started: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + str(time) + bcolors.ENDC)
                print(bcolors.BOLD + "Time now: " + bcolors.OKBLUE + str(datetime.now().time()) + bcolors.ENDC)
                print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "=" * 60 + bcolors.ENDC)
                t = Thread(target=connect, args=(server, para1, para2))
                t.start()
                t.join()


def read_test_files(hostsfile, paras1file, paras2file):
    hosts = open(hostsfile, 'r').readlines()
    paras1 = open(paras1file, 'r').readlines()
    paras2 = open(paras2file, 'r').readlines()
    generate_tests(hosts, paras1, paras2)


def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage python test.py -H <hosts file> -U <para1 file> -P <para2 file>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='hostsfile', help="specify host file to test")
    parser.add_option('-U', dest='paras1file', help="specify possible parameters1")
    parser.add_option('-P', dest='paras2file', help="specify possible parameters2")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if options.hostsfile and options.paras1file and options.paras2file:
        hostsfile = options.hostsfile
        paras1file = options.paras1file
        paras2file = options.paras2file
        read_test_files(hostsfile, paras1file, paras2file)

    else:
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great idea, but it will still check the websites where the keyword got found. Iam trying right now to get the script to work, maybe you have one more idea?

Comment: @beginner2022 It's my problem, I put `if host in white_list:` in front of `server = host.strip('\n\r')`, it should be this problem that caused the failure to judge. I made changes, you can try again.

Comment: Thank you ! i tried it out now a few times, and it's exactly what i wanted, but there is one problem why it doesn't work properly. `if "google" in r2.text:` `white_list.add(server)` will add all websites to the white_list that passed the check. If i `print(white_list)` i will see all the websites that passed the check, so all good. But if i print it in the for loop, i will just get the output "set()". Thats the reason why `if server in white_list:` doesnt work, because there are no websites in white_list

Comment: If i manually do `white_list = "http://google.com/", "http://gmail.com/"` instead of `white_list = set()` all working fine. Do you know why?

Comment: @beginner2022 The problem is found, because there is no waiting for the child thread to execute `white_list.add(server)`, the `for` loop in the main thread has been executed, you can add `t.join()` after `t.start()` to solve this problem.

Comment: After adding `thread.join()`, the requests are executed in sequence, which reduces the efficiency, so generally the whitelist defines the value at the time of initialization.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i learned a lot today